# Avatar command doesn't show the profile picture

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making an avatar command, and it shows the users name in the embed, but not the actual avatar.

```
if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + 'avatar')) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setImage(user.avatarURL)
        .setAuthor(user.username)
        .setColor(0x7732a8);
    message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
}
```

[image: a screenshot of the command]

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! Which version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to solve,
[user#avatarURL()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL) is a function, so just add () after it.